# Oracle VM: “No space left on device” But Space Exists

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Oracle 5.0.8 VirtualBox Manager. I am running Kali Linux as a VM inside this manager. This VM has a fixed size of 16 GB. I recently ran a dist-upgrade inside the VM and it ran out of space while upgrading. The VM then crashed. When it was restarted the VM displayed the Grub bootloader, then the classic Linux boot, but never displayed the gnome GUI. All that is displayed is a blank screen. I am able to access the virtual console. I cloned the vdi and made it into a dynamically-allocated drive. Then I resized this drive to be a 20GB drive. As I ran sudo apt-get upgrade through the virtual console, I was presented with:

> dpkg was interuppted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct this problem

I ran "sudo dpkg --configure -a" and then was presented with this error

> Error: failed to write status database record about 'libmono-system-runtime2.0-cil' to '/var/lib/dpkg/status': No space left on device

I did replace the old vdi SATA controller with the new dynamically-allocated vdi. When I run "fdisk --list" it shows that the controller is 20GB. How do I fix these errors and get back to my GUI. Any explaining of these errors would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It sounds as if you resized the disk, but did not resize the filesystem(s) inside the VM.  You should compare the sizes shown from `df -h` and `fdisk -l` to see that the total sizes match.

Comment: Yep; you can't just slap in a larger disk: you have to resize the partitions/filesystems.